# How do I get a vm to detect integrated camera?

Tags: vmware-player

I have an IBM ThinkPad T500 running Windows 7, and a Windows 7 VM running through VMWare Player. Nevermind the why. How do I get the integrated camera to be detected by the VM?

Comment: This may belong on superuser, but that place scares me, so I'm starting here.

Comment: Did you connect the USB device to the VM via the USB menu in VMWare?

Comment: @Nate I tried that right after I posted. It's 'almost' working now. The app sees the camera, but it's not picking up any video.

Comment: Why does it scare you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrated cameras typically show up as USB devices. VMware will allow you to connect the USB device to the virtual machine. Of course, the **[integrated camera driver](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-70600)** will need to be installed to the VM guest operating system in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the options but failed to get it to work with my HP TrueVision Webcam. I had trouble installing its driver as it showed that "Webcam not found, please plug it in and press install again". My laptop was HP 15-d103tx with VMware 12 pro. The cam was working on Youcam and Chrome and Skype on Windows 7 64bit.

VMware would show error that "the connection for chicony hp truevision was unsuccessful"

My options:

1) get a new USB webcam and try again. or maybe try to utilise my mobile cam.

2) My BIOS won't let me Moving the device from a USB 3.0 port to a USB 2.0 port as it showed only Auto(USB 2.0 pre-boot) and Enable for USB 3.0

**My solution was to use my mobile cam through [Droidcam](https://www.dev47apps.com/)**

> You get a client for Windows and Ubuntu.

- *You can get a client for Windows over [here](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/windows/)*
- *You can get it for ubuntu over [here](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/)*
- *You can install the app from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam)*

> **Bonus**: code for installing client for ubuntu

```
cd /tmp/
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
bits=`getconf LONG_BIT`
wget https://www.dev47apps.com/files/600/droidcam-${bits}bit.tar.bz2
tar xjf droidcam-${bits}bit.tar.bz2
cd droidcam-${bits}bit/
sudo ./install
```

Now to use your mobile cam, type `droidcam` in terminal and open app on mobile and type the IP and port number as shown on mobile and both laptop and mobile should be connected to same Wifi.

To test: use `cheese`
if you don't have it already, `sudo apt-get install cheese` and you can see that mobile webcam is indeed working. You can also connect it though USB(adb) instead of wifi.